# Java generic type bounds and runtime construction check

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

I am trying to create a builder which would help me to construct an object graph implemented using decorator pattern. I want the builder to be as reliable as possible, but it fails when generics are introduced with type bounds. That is it constructs an object graph which will fail when decorator "workflow" is called with "Cannot cast X to Y" error.

Builder usage:

```
    Processor<XyzContext> processor = Builder.create(new XyzProcessor())
        .persist()
        .handleRequest()
        .build();
```

Builder class used to decorate the original processor:

```
class Builder<T> {

    Processor<T> processor;

    Builder(Processor<T> processor) {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    static <T> Builder<T> create(Processor<T> processor) {
        return new Builder<T>(processor);
    }

    Builder<T> handleRequest() {
        processor = new RequestHandlingProcessor(processor);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder<T> persist() {
        processor = new PersistingProcessor(processor);
        return this;
    }

    public Processor<T> build() {
        return processor;
    }

}
```

Persisting processor (being decorated)

```
public class PersistingProcessor<T> implements Processor<T> {
    private final Processor<T> delegate;

    public PersistingProcessor(Processor<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(T request) {
        // save to db
    }
}
```

Request handling decorator

```
public class RequestHandlingProcessor<T extends RawRequestHolder> 
        implements Processor<T> {

    private final Processor<T> delegate;

    public RequestHandlingProcessor(Processor<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(T context) {
        context.getRawRequest(); <------- RawRequestHolder interface used
        delegate.process(context);
    }

}
```

The context class

```
public class XyzContext implements RawRequestHolder {

   // Implementor of above interface

    public XyzContext(String request) { ... }

    @Override
    public String getRawRequest() { ... }

}
```

When I would use this builder for a different Context class, e.g. AbcContext class which does not implement RawRequestHolder, I would know about this unbound type error too late (when the decorated processor would be used for the first time to process something by throwing ClassCastException).

When I construct the graph using constructors only:

```
    new RequestHandlingProcessor<XyzContext>(
        new PersistingProcessor<XyzContext>(
            new AbcProcessor()
        )
    );
```

then I, of course, get a compilation error that AbcContext is out of type bounds.

Is there some pattern or a way that it throws error during construction using the "dynamic" builder too? The builder would be used to create a Spring bean, so it would be awesome if it could throw an error during construction (app context would not start).

I know about type erasure, but was curious if there is some better way then using ugly nested constructors.

Comment: You have a lot of code there; and I am wondering if a "minimal" viable example does need to be that large here. In other words: i cant say if this is a good question; or not so much.

Comment: I know but I think it has to be to understand the problem. Maybe two processors was enough, but this illustrates the problem in more detail. The code does not do much, it's just java boilerplate.

Comment: Obviously your input hasnt created any feedback for 5 hours; that usually means that people dont know what to do about it. So, the best advise I have: step back, and see if you can somehow "peel the onion"; and come up with a "more dense" question around your topic.

Comment: So you want to check if the 'abcContext' (in this case) implements both 'RequestEntityHolder' and 'RawRequestHolder' interfaces? So why would a simple `instanceof` check not work?

Comment: Because it is duplication of what Java should already now, so to speak. I want to minimize human error in e.g. forgetting the instaceof or when bounds change, forgetting to change the check also, creating more situation where dev can make a mistake.

Comment: Also, I simplified the question to only one bound (RawRequestHolder)

Comment: Than you should ask yourself, should the genericType in all the layers implement the specific interfaces? If so, you can use `T extends RequestEntityHolder, RawRequestHolder` to make sure a generictype implements both interfaces. Otherwise an `instanceof` check is the way to go.

Comment: No, it's not necessary. The interface is there so the one particular processor can deal with expected interface to do some work. Other processors can need different (unrelated) interfaces for their processing. There can be many different layers in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to do instanceof check dynamically (without instanceof)? I.e. get the type bounds of the processor class and check if that particular delegate passed to the constructor is a subclass of those?

Comment: There is no way to get genericType information at runTime at the moment, other than cast directly and catch the `ClassCastException` in case the object didnt have the correct genericType. So either only expose the Builder class for Processor construction, or change the genericType (which may make the system less flexible).